# ShinobiChart ignoring series made of 0s

Tags: shinobi

I'm using ShinobiControls for creating a simple chart. When the dataset is:

```
@{
   @"Value": @0.0,
   @"Date": @1364828400
 },
@{
   @"Value": @0.0,
   @"Date": @1364914800
  },
@{
   @"Value": @0.0,
   @"Date": @1365001200
 }
]
```

I receive this error message:

```
Ignoring range with 0.000000 span
From: SChartNumberAxis at 0xc287030, axisRange = { 0.000000, 0.000000 }, defaultRange = { 0.000000, 0.000000 }, maxRange = { 0.000000, 0.000000 }
```

and my app gets stuck. No error message. Nothing.

Has anybody seen anything similar?

Comment: I'm confused.  You receive the given error message, but then you say there is no error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you have not set range for the axis tied to the Value dimension of your points. Supposing that value is displayed on the Y axis. Try:

```
SChartNumberRange *yAxisRange = [[SChartNumberRange alloc] initWithMinimum:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] andMaximum:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10]];
    SChartNumberAxis *yAxis = [[SChartNumberAxis alloc] initWithRange:yAxisRange];
```